# Google Apps Script query to MariaDB

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, mariadb

We recently moved our data to a new server - however the new one is using MariaDB.

We do a lot of queries and calculations in Google Apps Script for spreadsheet. Since the server switch our scripts return the following error:

> Unknown system variable 'OPTION' (line 21, file "")

Line 21 refers to the query inside the following script:

```
function mysql_invoice() {

// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'xxx';
var user = 'xxx';
var userPwd = 'xxx';
var db = 'xxx';

var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

// Read up to 100000 rows of data from the table and log them.

     var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd); 
      var stmt = conn.createStatement();


  // Call SO DATA 
      stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
      var start = new Date();

      var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from sales_flat_invoice");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There isn't enough info in your question to reproduce the problem. A [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: To reproduce the problem you have to create a google script which is trying to access to a remote database server running MariaDB and you should use JDBC:mysql drivers to access and run queries on it. All the information is provided in the question as I can see. What else you need? Can you be more specific about that?

Comment: If you are using MariaDB 10 with an older version of jdbc driver then it will more likely give you these kind of errors.

MySql 5.5 is compariable with Maria DB 5.5 and MySql 5.6 is Compariable with MariaDB 10. The difference between MySql 5.5 and 5.6 is the support for OPTION. 5.6 is not supporting that any more.
So, if you are using MariaDB 10 you dont have support for system variable OPTION which is being used in the jdbc Driver most likely to prepare and run the query. 
My strong guess is that you need to use an updated version of jdbc if it is possible with google scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the way you used setMaxRows is the problem.

If you change the way you set the limit it will work.

```
  // Call SO DATA 
  //      stmt.setMaxRows(10000);
  var start = new Date();

  var rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from sales_flat_invoice limit 10000");
```

This should fix your problem. This definetly comes from the missmatch of version of your MariaDB and the version of jdbc connector.

Cheers