# How to connect a google spreadsheet to my MariaDB?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mariadb

I can connect remotely with navicat, no problem, but when i'm trying to do that in google app script, I get the next error: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.

I use the following function to connect:

```
function getConnection(){

  var address = 'url.domain';
  var user = 'username'; 
  var userPwd = 'pass'; 
  var db = 'database_name';
  var spreadsheetURL = 'spreadsheetURL'; 


  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  return conn;
}
```

The inserted data is correct;
I tried with a password with no special characters. 
The spreadsheet is shareable, anyone with the link can edit.

Comment: The version of JDBC used by Apps Script probably doesn't support MariaDB.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810115/google-apps-script-query-to-mariadb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [connect to mariadb using google scripts,error:Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221493/connect-to-mariadb-using-google-scripts-errorconnection-url-uses-an-unsupported)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to whitelist your CIDR IP address ranges as per this documentation:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#creating_google_cloud_sql_connections

Also, Google recommends using the Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(url) method instead if you wish to not have to whitelist IP addresses.